# How to get the local API url in custom command

Tags: python, django

I want to call the local API

I can access this from `wget`

`wget http://localhost:8000/api/item`

So the code below works

```
get_url_info = requests.get('http://localhost:8000/api/items')
print(get_url_info)
```

However, url could be changed depending on server (ex `http://localhost:8000/` -> `http://localhost/`

How should I access to the local API???

Comment: Hi @whitebear, I assumed that you call the same API, so why the url could be changed, can you add more detail about it

Comment: For example, development environment using `python manage.py runserver` port 8000 like  `127.0.0.1:8000` but on production environment using apache port 80.

Comment: Or you can write a config file for production, development, ... There is built-in module for config parser in Python with name `configparser`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this:

```
# put all possible urls in a list:
urls = [ 'url1', 'url2', 'url3', ...]

# iterate over each url:
for url in urls:

    try:

        # try to access url:
        url_info = requests.get(url)

        # break out of the loop if successfull:
        break

    except:

        # continue to next url in list:
        pass
```